# Which post-hoc test to run with Wilcoxon signed rank sum test in R?

Tags: r, posthoc, bonferroni

I have ran a Wilcoxon signed rank sum test on my paired data in R. my code is:

```r
plot.wilcox <- wilcox.test(score ~ time, data = data, paired = TRUE)
```

Which post hoc test to use that would accompany the Wilcoxon signed rank sum test?

I plugged in:

```r
plot.wilcox.bonferroni <- data %>% 
  wilcox.test(score ~ Category_time, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni") 
plot.wilcox.bonferroni
```

Obviously, an error comes up. I also don't know if Bonferroni adjustment is the proper post hoc test. Should I be conducting a Dunn test, not sure if Dunn test if for paired data. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO, denise! I think my answer will suffice, but if not: please make this question more *reproducible*. This typically includes sample code you've attempted (you've done this, thanks!) and sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess at your error: the `%>%`-pipe is placing the data as the first unnamed argument in the `wilcox.test`. There are two ways to call that function, described in [`?wilcox.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html):

```
     ## Default S3 method:
     wilcox.test(x, y = NULL,
                 alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
                 mu = 0, paired = FALSE, exact = NULL, correct = TRUE,
                 conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95,
                 tol.root = 1e-4, digits.rank = Inf, ...)
     
     ## S3 method for class 'formula'
     wilcox.test(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...)
```

In general, `%>%`-piping allows you the option to specify which argument gets the data by using the special `.` symbol. When that is not included, it goes in the first *unname* argument.

So this is what I think you are seeing (using `airquality`, taken from examples in the doc for that function):

```r
library(dplyr) # or library(magrittr)
airquality %>%
  wilcox.test(Ozone ~ Month, subset = Month %in% c(5, 8))
# Error in wilcox.test.default(., Ozone ~ Month, subset = Month %in% c(5,  : 
#   'x' must be numeric
```

This is because the function takes as its first unnamed argument with `x` (numeric) or `formula`, a formula (aptly-named).

For this function, you really only have one option to use `%>%` to feed the data: provide the `.` symbol to the `data=` argument, by-name.

```r
airquality %>%
  wilcox.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = ., subset = Month %in% c(5, 8))
# Warning in wilcox.test.default(x = DATA[[1L]], y = DATA[[2L]], ...) :
#   cannot compute exact p-value with ties
#   Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
# data:  Ozone by Month
# W = 127.5, p-value = 0.0001208
# alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Since we're using `data=.`, you can choose to put it almost anywhere, though if you move `Ozone ~ Month`, you should likely name it as well, with `formula = Ozone ~ Month`.

---

For you, I suspect then that this will work:

```r
plot.wilcox.bonferroni <- data %>% 
  wilcox.test(score ~ Category_time, data = .,
              paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```